# How to compare existing fields from object1 in object2 in javascript tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I should compare existing all fields and values from `object1` in `object2`

example:

```
object1: {
  user: {
    id: 25,
    name: "Elon"
  }
};

object2: {
  user: {
    id: 25,
    name: "Elon",
    role: "admin"
  },
  rules: [
    "edit"
  ]
}

compareFn(object1, object2); //true
```

I can write this function, but I think that it exist in some testing framework, but I have not found :(

Can you help me? Thx!

Comment: Maybe this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: this is deepEqual, but in my version

comparing: {a: 5} and {a: 5, b: 10} should be true

Comment: and I dont want to provide self solutions. Testing frameworks have this function. assert.deepEqual, or should.deepEqual. I want to use existing solution in my happening

Comment: Jest has an objectContaining method that should do what you need. It is explained here: https://medium.com/@boriscoder/the-hidden-power-of-jest-matchers-f3d86d8101b0

Comment: Yeah, it's true... above link is not for your case

Answer (score 0):

The test framework Jest would allow you do achieve this. Using their toMatchObject assertion. Your code would look like:

```
const object1 = {
  user: {
    id: 25,
    name: "Elon"
  }
};

const object2 = {
  user: {
    id: 25,
    name: "Elon",
    role: "admin"
  },
  rules: [
    "edit"
  ]
}

test('object1 found within object2', () => {
    expect(object2).toMatchObject(object1);
});
```

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject